# Solve the problem with the currency converter js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a converter, but I have some problem with the json link, I looked in the console, everything is displayed normally in the console, all objects, namely in the converter, do not work, I realized that you need to specifically specify the reference to the currencies, but how to implement this? Thanks in advance.

```js
const currencyEl_one = document.getElementById('currency-one');
const currencyEl_two = document.getElementById('currency-two');
const amountEl_one = document.getElementById('amount-one');
const amountEl_two = document.getElementById('amount-two');

const rateEl = document.getElementById('rate');
const swap = document.getElementById('swap');

// Fetch exchange rates and update the dome
function converter() {
  const currency_one = currencyEl_one.value;
  const currency_two = currencyEl_two.value;

  fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json${currency_one}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      const rate = data.conversion_rates[currency_two];
      rateEl.innerText = `1 ${currency_one} = ${rate} ${currency_two}`;

      amountEl_two.value = (amountEl_one.value * rate).toFixed(2);
    });
}

// Event Listeners
currencyEl_one.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountEl_one.addEventListener('input', converter);
currencyEl_two.addEventListener('change', converter);
amountEl_two.addEventListener('input', converter);
swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const temp = currencyEl_one.value;
  currencyEl_one.value = currencyEl_two.value;
  currencyEl_two.value = temp;
  converter();
});

converter();
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #5fbaa7;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 450ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  word-break: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.swap-rate-container .btn-arrows {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0.54;
  transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indent-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/ServiceCurrency.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

b {
  font-weight: var(--tw-semi);
}

.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.currency select {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%20000002%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  background-position: right 10px top 50%, 0, 0;
  background-size: 12px auto, 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.currency select:hover {}

input[type="number"]:hover {}

select {
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.currency input {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 68%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.currency input:hover {}

.select-placeholder {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

@media (maz-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Currency Converter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="indent-right"></div>
      <b>Конвертер валют</b>
    </div>
    <div class="currency">
      <select id="currency-one">
        <option class="select-placeholder">Виберите</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <div class="flag_usd">
          <div style="display: flex;">
            <option value="USD" selected>
              USD
            </option>
            <svg height="24px" width="24px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path 
            d="M12.192 10.868c-1.736-.438-2.294-.892-2.294-1.597 0-.81.772-1.373 2.065-1.373 1.362 0 1.867.631 1.913 1.56h1.69c-.054-1.28-.817-2.502-2.634-2.92V5h-1.805v1.517c-1.673.255-2.99 1.335-2.99 2.769 0 1.715 1.461 2.57 3.595 3.067 1.913.445 2.295 1.1 2.295 1.79 0 .512-.375 1.329-2.065 1.329-1.576 0-2.195-.683-2.295-1.56H8c.092 1.627 1.596 2.908 3.127 2.908v1.548h1.805v-1.53c1.498 0 2.855-1.18 2.855-2.703 0-2.109-1.859-2.822-3.595-3.267z" 
            fill="#000" 
            fill-rule="evenodd" 
            stroke="none" 
            stroke-width="1">                             
            </path>
          </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
      </select>
      <input type="number" id="amount-one" placeholder="200" />
    </div>

    <div class="swap-rate-container">
      <button class="btn" id="swap">
        <div class="btn-arrows">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <svg
            height="24px"
            width="24px"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <g
              fill="none"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1"
            >
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M6.99 11L3 15l3.99 4v-3H14v-2H6.99v-3zM21 9l-3.99-4v3H10v2h7.01v3L21 9z"
                fill="#000"
                fill-rule="nonzero"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
      <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="currency">
      <select id="currency-two">
        <option class="select-placeholder">Виберите</option>
        <option value="UAH" selected>UAH</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
      <input type="number" id="amount-two" placeholder="200" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The data returned doesn't appear to contain a `conversion_rates` property. You appear to be doing `data.conversion_rates[currency_two]` where `data` is an array of objects, which doesn't seem like it will ever achieve an intended result.

Comment: @DBS, Do you know how to fix it, in some projects I dealt with json, but there was something else, but how to implement it correctly here?

Answer (score 1):

Your call is incorrect

The API call you make returns Hryvna only.

Here is the correct code for when you fix the API call

Change the second currency to USD to see a currently incorrect result

Also I changed the event handler to delegate from container

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const currencyEl_one = document.getElementById('currency-one');
const currencyEl_two = document.getElementById('currency-two');
const amountEl_one = document.getElementById('amount-one');
const amountEl_two = document.getElementById('amount-two');
const rateEl = document.getElementById('rate');
const swap = document.getElementById('swap');

// Fetch exchange rates and update the dome
function converter() {
  const currency_one = currencyEl_one.value;
  const currency_two = currencyEl_two.value;

  fetch(`https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json=${currency_one}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // console.log(data);
      const rate = data.find(({cc})=> cc === currency_two);
      // console.log(rate); // rate.rate is the value you want
      rateEl.innerText = `1 ${currency_one} = ${rate.rate} ${currency_two}`;

      amountEl_two.value = (amountEl_one.value * rate.rate).toFixed(2);
    });
}

// Event Listeners
container.addEventListener('change', converter);
container.addEventListener('change', converter);
swap.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const temp = currencyEl_one.value;
  currencyEl_one.value = currencyEl_two.value;
  currencyEl_two.value = temp;
  converter();
});

converter();
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #5fbaa7;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 57px;
  height: 44px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition-duration: 450ms;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  word-break: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.swap-rate-container .btn-arrows {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  opacity: 0.54;
  transition: opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.indent-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.privat24.ua/icons/file/ServiceCurrency.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px !important;
}

b {
  font-weight: var(--tw-semi);
}

.currency {
  padding: 40px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.currency select {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%20000002%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  background-position: right 10px top 50%, 0, 0;
  background-size: 12px auto, 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.currency select:hover {}

input[type="number"]:hover {}

select {
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-right: -17px;
}

.currency input {
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
  border-style: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  width: 68%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.currency input:hover {}

.select-placeholder {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}

.swap-rate-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.rate {
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

@media (maz-width: 600px) {
  .currency input {
    width: 200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Currency Converter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="indent-right"></div>
      <b>Конвертер валют</b>
    </div>
    <div class="currency">
      <select id="currency-one">
        <option class="select-placeholder">Виберите</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <div class="flag_usd">
          <div style="display: flex;">
            <option value="USD" selected>
              USD
            </option>
            <svg height="24px" width="24px" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path 
            d="M12.192 10.868c-1.736-.438-2.294-.892-2.294-1.597 0-.81.772-1.373 2.065-1.373 1.362 0 1.867.631 1.913 1.56h1.69c-.054-1.28-.817-2.502-2.634-2.92V5h-1.805v1.517c-1.673.255-2.99 1.335-2.99 2.769 0 1.715 1.461 2.57 3.595 3.067 1.913.445 2.295 1.1 2.295 1.79 0 .512-.375 1.329-2.065 1.329-1.576 0-2.195-.683-2.295-1.56H8c.092 1.627 1.596 2.908 3.127 2.908v1.548h1.805v-1.53c1.498 0 2.855-1.18 2.855-2.703 0-2.109-1.859-2.822-3.595-3.267z" 
            fill="#000" 
            fill-rule="evenodd" 
            stroke="none" 
            stroke-width="1">                             
            </path>
          </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="UAH">UAH</option>
      </select>
      <input type="number" id="amount-one" placeholder="200" />
    </div>

    <div class="swap-rate-container">
      <button class="btn" id="swap">
        <div class="btn-arrows">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <svg
            height="24px"
            width="24px"
            version="1.1"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <g
              fill="none"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
              stroke="none"
              stroke-width="1"
            >
              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z"></path>
              <path
                d="M6.99 11L3 15l3.99 4v-3H14v-2H6.99v-3zM21 9l-3.99-4v3H10v2h7.01v3L21 9z"
                fill="#000"
                fill-rule="nonzero"
              ></path>
            </g>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </button>
      <div class="rate" id="rate"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="currency">
      <select id="currency-two">
        <option class="select-placeholder">Виберите</option>
        <option value="UAH" selected>UAH</option>
        <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
      </select>
      <input type="number" id="amount-two" placeholder="200" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```